# copy a full directory (all levels) from one server to many servers

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy

I have a

linux server : a1
it's local disk is : /scratch 
a directory in local disk is : /scratch/builda

/builda has over 100K files and is about 100GB

My compute cluster has about 100 servers - a1 through a100

I need to copy a:/scratch/builda to a2 - a100 under the same structure. Copy required for ALL files under builda and need to keep structure same, permissions same, checksum same etc.

I have tried rscyn --recursive a1:/scratch/builda a2:/scratch  (thro a100)
I have tried scp 
I have tried to automate ftp

I have looked at using parallel with rsycn

all of these are slow or break down after 10 or 12 run - and then slow down - and then I can't predict when they complete.

I read about grid-ftp - but seems complicated and i don't quite get globus.

Any help.

I need to do this on both Windows (b1:x:\builda to b2-b100:x:\builda) and on linux (a1:/scratch/builda to a2-a100:/scratch/builda) fast and password less (or with a ssh key)

thanks

Comment: it needs to be automated - may be like once a day at 2PM when the build completes.

Comment: write a shell script, To automate everything